# What proportion of the Arab population of Palestine pre-1948 came from families that lived there before 1880?

Tags: israel, jews, palestine

It is known that the population of Palestine increased greatly between, say, 1880 and 1948. Apart from Jewish immigration there was also considerable Arab immigration (partly related to the economic impetus the Jews immigrants supplied to the land). Are there statistics that say which proportion of the Arabs in Palestine in 1948 came from families that lived there before 1880?

Comment: I canot really tell what you are asking, and the bits I've understood, though it was probably not your intention, could spark nationalistic and patriotic feelings. Plus, it would probably solicit debate. I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to vote to close this.

Comment: Although it is difficult to answer with a precise number, certainly *most* of the refugees are indeed descendants, as can be read in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_people#Palestinian_history_and_nationalism I voted to close because it seems to me that you did not do minimal research work before asking. Also, it seems to me you are adding an unnecessary frame of opinions. I suggest you edit the question. Best

Comment: rephrase the question.

Comment: Edited and voted to reopen.

Comment: Because of the political implications, that in turn have flame implications, I suggest you elaborate on the sentence "there was also considerable Arab immigration (partly related to the economic impetus the Jews immigrants supplied to the land)." especially adding the source(s) of this statement. How can such a statement be done without statistics about the population of Palestine before 1948? Your source is likely to contain the most important information needed for an answer.

Comment: I think this is valid after the edit. The fact it is a contentious topic isn't important.

Comment: Jews claim that the land is effectively worthless desert before they come back. Also it is indeed worthless desert. It's the jews that make it rich.

Comment: The political implication can means peace by the way. If we stick with reality rather than fairy tales things may work better, or worse...

Comment: http://unispal.un.org/UNISPAL.NSF/0/07175DE9FA2DE563852568D3006E10F3   a paragraph or so under  "5. Access to the sea for the Arab State"

Comment: @NathanCooper: But how does this answer the question?

Comment: Actually why does UN define refugee as someone coming within 2 years of 1948 anyway? I mean that's kind of short. If some guy has been there for hundreds of years and got kicked out like Muhammad kicking out Banu Nadir, that's an issue. But 2 years? C'mon. Just find another job and got cash for the land or something.

Comment: @JimThio: You might have a point there, but let's try to stick to the history and keep aside from the polemics.

Comment: And how many of those 689k people are now "refugees"?

Comment: @JimThio: That's a rather different question. You may want to ask it in a separate thread.

Comment: 407,000 Arabs and other in the Jewish state (proposals)
725,000 in the Arab state
105,000 in Jerusalem.  

498,000 Jews in the Jewish state
10,000 in the Arab state
100,000 in Jerusalem

plus 90,000 Bedouins, cultivators and stock owners who seek grazing further afield in dry seasons.    ++The question changed since I commented. It was about populations.

Comment: Basically how many arabs are there on 1940 and how many are there in 1948

Comment: Given that a lot of Arab had no fixed homes and moves about with live stock etc, it is very hard to say what "lived in" even means.....

Comment: Note that population in that time wasn't even remotely as accurately traced as we'd do today.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you're interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Palestine#The_question_of_late_Arab_immigration_to_Palestine

The data to answer your question is immigration stats as exact measures of hereditary do not exist. You could always subtract net immigration from population increases to get a upper bound. (You could do some maths and model immigrant pop growth, but this would be hard and would result in spurious accuracy in this case).

The statement: "there was also considerable Arab immigration (partly related to the economic impetus the Jews immigrants supplied to the land)" is questionable. And the link above should help explore whether this statement is indeed true. For instance, people point out the 1931 census of Palestine only shows 2% of Arabs were born abroad at that time, but others think most immigration was unrecorded etc: a few essays worth of disagreement basically. Since it is a Israel/Palestine issue it is well cited, enjoy.